# Why do Keras Tuners' Fixed hyperparameters produce different results from static values?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters

My hypertuning results are quite different even though my model should effectively be using the same parameters, depending on whether I use `hp.Fixed(key, value)` or just `value` (where `value` is say, an Int). I've verified that repeated runs of each test produce the same results following the [instructions for reproducibility](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) as well as setting the seed for all applicable layers/initializers/etc. even though the instructions stated they weren't necessary.

### **Using `hp.Fixed(key, value)`**

[image: Using hp.Fixed(key, value)]

### Using `value`

[image: Using value]

Looking at the table of all hyperparameters, it appears that `hp.Fixed` isn't even doing anything at all. All hyperparameters are being tested.

EDIT: My custom hypermodel's hyperparameters regardless of state are being ignored by the HyperbandTuner.

---

Here is the offending code:

```
class MyModel(kt.HyperModel):
    def __init__(self, **config):
        self.config = config
        self.seed = config.get('seed')
    
    def build_model(self):
        model = Sequential(name=self.name)
        model.add(LSTM(self.units, name='LSTM'))
        model.add(Dense(1, name='Output', kernel_initializer=GlorotUniform(seed=self.seed)))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', metrics='mean_squared_error', sample_weight_mode='temporal')
        return model
    
    # If the user has supplied the parameter manually, use hp.Fixed()
    # Otherwise, use the provided hyperparameter (default)
    def _param(self, key, default=None):
        value = self.config.get(key)
        if value is not None:
            return self.hp.Fixed(key, value)
        else:
            return default

    def build(self, hp):
        self.hp = hp
        self.units = self._param('units', hp.Int('units', 1, 200, step=5))
        return self.build_model()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after doing some more digging I discovered (specifically through how [this tutorial](https://reposhub.com/python/deep-learning/keras-team-keras-tuner.html#:%7E:text=hp%20%3D%20HyperParameters()%0A%23%20This%20will%20override%20the%20%60learning_rate%60%20parameter%20with%20your%0A%23%20own%20selection%20of%20choices%0Ahp.Choice(%27learning_rate%27%2C%20values%3D%5B1e-2%2C%201e-3%2C%201e-4%5D)) declared the hyperparameters) that when you write `hp.[Fixed|Choice|etc.]`, you are immediately declaring the presence of those hyperparameters in the search space, regardless of where that code appears.

Think of the hyperparameter declaration as an eigenclass method, not as a regular Python object that the HyperTuner picks up on from within the model.

Essentially, each of the Fixed/Choice/etc. hyperparameter methods simultaneously sets a global hyperparameter somewhere in the background of the HyperTuner class while also returning a regular variable (Int/Float/String/Range/List/etc.) so that you can still build your model without error before the HyperTuner eventually overwrites it during the search phase.

I was confused by this because typically the `hp` shows up as an argument in the `build_model()` method or `kt.HyperModel` class wherein the calls are assigned to local variables which are then passed to the model declaration.

---

Here's the fix for the offending code:

```
class MyModel(kt.HyperModel):
    def __init__(self, **config):
        self.config = config
        self.seed = config.get('seed')
    
    def build_model(self):
        model = Sequential(name=self.name)
        model.add(LSTM(self.units, name='LSTM'))
        model.add(Dense(1, name='Output', kernel_initializer=GlorotUniform(seed=self.seed)))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', metrics='mean_squared_error', sample_weight_mode='temporal')
        return model
    
    # If the user has supplied the parameter manually, use hp.Fixed()
    # Otherwise, use the provided hyperparameter (default)
    def _param(self, key, default=None):
        value = self.config.get(key)
        if value is not None:
            return self.hp.Fixed(key, value)
        else:
            return default()

    def build(self, hp):
        self.hp = hp
        self.units = self._param('units', lambda: hp.Int('units', 1, 200, step=5))
        return self.build_model()
```